# Row lumping, cycle dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, cycle, gaps-and-islands

I want to look at the `lead` type and if that type is the same for that row then merge in those dates to fit within one row.

I have the below table:

```
id    start_dt     end_dt    type
 1     1/1/19      2/21/19   cross
 1     2/22/19     6/5/19    cross
 1     6/6/19      8/31/19   cross
 1     9/1/19      10/3/19   AAAA
 1     10/4/19     10/4/19   cross
 1     10/5/19     10/6/19   AAAA
 1     10/7/19     10/10/19  AAAA
 1     10/11/19    12/31/99  cross
```

Expected Results:

```
 id    start_dt    end_dt    type
 1     1/1/19      8/31/19   cross
 1     9/1/19      10/3/19   AAAA
 1     10/4/19     10/4/19   cross
 1     10/5/19     10/10/19  AAAA
 1     10/11/19    12/31/99  cross
```

How can I get my output to look like the expected results?

I have tested with`lead` `lag` `rank` and `case expression` but nothing worthy of adding here. Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [`gaps-and-islands`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+oracle) problem. One option for solving it through contribution of `row_number()` analytical function :

```
select min(start_dt) as startdate, max(end_dt) as enddate, type
  from
  (
   with t(id, start_dt, end_dt,type) as
   (
    select 1, date'2019-01-01', date'2019-02-21', 'cross' from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-02-22', date'2019-06-05', 'cross'  from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-06-06', date'2019-08-31', 'cross'  from dual union all  
    select 1, date'2019-09-01', date'2019-10-03', 'AAAA'  from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-09-04', date'2019-10-04', 'cross'  from dual union all   
    select 1, date'2019-10-05', date'2019-10-06', 'AAAA'  from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-10-07', date'2019-10-10', 'AAAA'  from dual union all  
    select 1, date'2019-10-11', date'2019-12-31', 'cross'  from dual 
   )
   select type, 
          row_number() over (partition by id, type order by end_dt) as rn1,
          row_number() over (partition by id order by end_dt) as rn2,
          start_dt, end_dt
     from t
   ) tt
 group by type, rn1 - rn2
 order by enddate;

STARTDATE   ENDDATE     TYPE
---------   ---------   -----
01-JAN-19   31-AUG-19   cross
01-SEP-19   03-OCT-19   AAAA
04-SEP-19   04-OCT-19   cross
05-OCT-19   10-OCT-19   AAAA
11-OCT-19   31-DEC-19   cross
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bde799475af56146597e5540f341d5e7)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I actually think this is a pretty good case for Oracle's Pattern Matching Functionality.

```sql
with t(id, start_dt, end_dt,type) as
   (
    select 1, date'2019-01-01', date'2019-02-21', 'cross' from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-02-22', date'2019-06-05', 'cross'  from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-06-06', date'2019-08-31', 'cross'  from dual union all  
    select 1, date'2019-09-01', date'2019-10-03', 'AAAA'  from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-09-04', date'2019-10-04', 'cross'  from dual union all   
    select 1, date'2019-10-05', date'2019-10-06', 'AAAA'  from dual union all
    select 1, date'2019-10-07', date'2019-10-10', 'AAAA'  from dual union all  
    select 1, date'2019-10-11', date'2019-12-31', 'cross'  from dual 
   )
SELECT *
FROM t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(ORDER BY start_dt
                MEASURES a.id AS ID,
                         A.start_dt AS START_DT,
                         NVL(LAST(B.end_dt), A.end_dt) AS END_DT,
                         a.type AS TYPE
                PATTERN (A B*)
                DEFINE B AS start_dt > PREV(start_dt) AND type = PREV(type));
```

A detailed primer on the topic can be found [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1)

Comment: Also, if you need to do this for all IDs, you simply need to add "PARTITION BY id" to the start of the MATCH_RECOGNIZE command. (And remove "a.id AS ID," from the MEASURES clause)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at *adjacent* rows to find groups that can combine, then I recommend `lag()` to find where groups start and a cumulative sum on that:

```
select id, type, min(start_dt), max(end_dt)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_dt >= start_dt - 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id, type order by start_dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_dt) over (partition by id, type order by start_dt) as prev_end_dt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, type, grp
order by id, min(start_dt);
```

In particular, this will find cases where the `type` does not change but there is a gap in the time frames, as shown by [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=125a5bb556a47d9defc313100cda057c) for id = 2.